# Asterisk / Elastix Address Book and Call Recording

Tags: voip, asterisk

I am trying to build a small asterisk based PBX using Elastix. It'll be having 4 FXO (2 nos.no ISDN, normal analog POTS, 2 nos. GSM connections using a GSM Terminal) and 4 FXS (2 IP Phones and 2 Android SIP Client).

I am confused about the following two issues and need your help:

1. I need to record all Incoming / Outgoing Calls along with their Caller Ids, Is any special hardware needed ?
2. I have about 5000-6000 contacts which I want to show up on my IP Phones menu, so that users can dial by selecting / searching the name / company. How can this be implemented and which is the most cost effective IP-Phone to purchase for contacts list of this size.

Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

For 1 you just need in all extensions(via web) select "record inbound" = yes, "record outbound"= yes.

For 2 that depend of phone. I know no free module to do what you requested,but you always able get developer to do that. Any cisco,aastra,policom phone can do xml browsing(specialy designed) so you able use it for contact list.